# NetworkX circular layout increase node spacing and custom positioning

Tags: python, matplotlib, networkx

I'm working with the [circular layout](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/generated/networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout.html#networkx.drawing.layout.circular_layout) graph on NetworkX.
I wanted to:

1. Increase spacing between nodes. I altered the scale but there seemed to be no change in the node spacing.

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(G, scale=2)
```

2. Place specific nodes next to one another in the circle (all nodes are labelled differently).

Thank you for any help!

Answer (score 0):

The second part of the question is the easier part. Since the `pos` returned by the `circular_layout` is only a `dict`, you can simply use the values:

```
import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pylab as pl
import random

g = nx.karate_club_graph()

pos = nx.circular_layout(g, )
node_order = list(g.nodes)
random.shuffle(node_order)
changed_pos = dict(zip(node_order, [pos[node] for node in g]))
```

The first part with the `scale` parameter is a little bit tricky, the scale parameter has an effect, but probably not that which you desire:

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos)
print(pl.gca().get_xlim())
# (-1.1, 1.1)
pl.show()


pos = nx.circular_layout(g, scale=200)
nx.draw(g, pos)
print(pl.gca().get_xlim())
# (-220.0, 220.0)
pl.show()
# same figure as above
```

As explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432240), "node sizes are given in display coordinates whereas node positions are given in data coordinates". (If you want in that answer a reference to [`netgraph`](https://github.com/paulbrodersen/netgraph) is included, which may help you - but I have no experience in using this package.)

To change the space between the nodes, you can increase the figure size or reduce the node size:

```
pos = nx.circular_layout(g)
nx.draw(g, pos, node_size=10)
pl.show()

pl.figure(figsize=(20,20))
nx.draw(g, pos)
pl.show()
```