# igraph layout that respects node size

Tags: python, graph, igraph

I want to plot a graph with igraph with different node sizes. Unfortunately, the layout algorithms are agnostic of the node size which can lead to overlapping nodes if the node size is large. Is there a way to adjust the layout for node sizes?

```py
import igraph as ig
g = ig.Graph()
g.add_vertices([0, 1,2,3])
g.add_edges([[0, 1], [0, 2],[0,3]])
ig.plot(g, vertex_size=[400, 20, 20,400])
```

[image: example graph]

Comment: Is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57432240/2912349) helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase the size of the plot with the `bbox` and `margin` arguments.

```
import igraph as ig

g = ig.Graph()
g.add_vertices([0, 1, 2, 3])
g.add_edges([[0, 1], [0, 2], [0, 3]])

ig.plot(
    g,
    "graph.png",
    vertex_size=[400, 20, 20, 400],
    margin=220,
    bbox=(0, 0, 1600, 1400),
)
```

[image]

It does not allow fine control, but at least you should be able to fit the plot in an image without having to reimplement the layout algorithm.